# how to set python environment variable in HP-UX OS?

Tags: python-2.7, hp-ux

I am new in HP-UX. I am trying to working with python in HP-UX. I have successfully install python download package from [hp-ux package](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Languages/python-2.7.10/)

But I can not set environment variable. Python successfully found in "/usr/local/bin". when I tried

```
python --version
```

it returned

```
python: command not found
```

How can I work with python in HP-UX ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the directory containing your Python interpreter is not on your `PATH`. Check if your `PATH` contains `/usr/local/bin`:

```
echo $PATH
```

If you do not see `/usr/local/bin` in there, you can add it to your path like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: thanks. looks it found python but raise another error.<br />

     `python --version`
    `/usr/lib/hpux32/dld.so: Unable to find library 'libexpat.so'.Killed`

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [python](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Languages/python-2.7.13/) and [expat](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Development/Tools/expat-2.2.3/) install package.
2. Install them by using `swinstall` in HP-UX.
3. Add `/usr/local/bin` to your system `PATH`.